# Nested query on attachment

Tags: attachment

I need to extract id from attachment Parent 'contact' then Contact Parent Id that is account.
Need to retrive attachment id , contact id related to that attachment and Account Id related to that Contact.
Can Anyone help me .

Comment: I assume you're looking for a SOQL query? What query or whatever have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT id,Name  ,Parentid,Description,Body FROM Attachment where ParentId in (Select id from Contact ) and  and Parent.Type='Contact'   - This is giving me Id of contact but I need contact ParentId also in the same query . Account Id

Comment: SELECT id,Name ,Parentid,Description,Body FROM Attachment where ParentId in (Select id from Contact ) and  Parent.Type='Contact' - This is giving me Id of contact but I need contact ParentId also in the same query . Account Id

Answer (score 1):

To get this in one query, you need the [TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) operator:

```
Attachment[] attachments = [
    SELECT ParentId, 
    TYPEOF Parent
        WHEN Contact THEN AccountId 
    END 
    FROM Attachment
    WHERE Parent.Type = 'Contact'
];
```

This query will return a structure similar to:

```
{
   Id: <<attachment id>>,
   Parent: {
     Id: <<contact id>>,
     AccountId: <<contact account id>>
   }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much I got the result